How to Create Macros for Quick Insertion of Mathematical Formulas in TeXstudio?
I'm looking for some guidance on how to efficiently insert mathematical formulas in TeXstudio using macros. Specifically, I want to achieve the following functionalities:

When I type mk in the text environment (I'm not sure if this is the correct terminology, as I want to distinguish it from the math environment denoted by $$), it should automatically insert $$, placing the cursor between them. After I finish typing the formula, I want to press a shortcut key that will move the cursor to the right side of the $$ and automatically insert a space. I believe I've already managed to achieve this by customizing a text macro with $%<%>$ %<%>.

When I'm in the math environment ($$) and type sum, I would like it to automatically expand to \sum_{<subscript>}^{<superscript>}<expression>, with the cursor positioned at <expression>. Upon pressing the shortcut key, the cursor should move to the <subscript>, and pressing it again should move to the <superscript>.


My main questions are:

How can I specify that the trigger is only effective in certain environments (for example, I do not want sum to be replaced in the text environment; I only want it to work in the math environment)?
How can I specify the order in which the cursor jumps between different placeholders?

Any help or pointers to relevant resources would be greatly appreciated!

You should never use $$ in latex, so don't make an editor shortcut to generate that, use \[..\] to make a diplay math formula.

@David Carlisle Thanks for the reminder :D
